# Compare dates with timedelta with Flask/SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm having a problem trying to compare two dates using timedelta under Sqlalchemy.

I have 2 tables defined by:

```
def Publication(Model):
    __tablename__ = "publications"
    ...
    publish_date = Column(DateTime)
    ...
    publication_type_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("publications_type.id")
    publication_type = relationship("PublicationType")
    ...

def PublicationType(Model):
    __tablename__ = "publications_type"
    ...
    duration_time = Column(Integer)
    ...
```

What I'm trying to do:

```
publications = Publication.query.filter(Publications.publish_date > datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=PublicationType.duration_time)).limit(10)
```

Error displayed:

```
TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: InstrumentedAttribute
```

Comment: What DB are you using? Python's `timedelta` is of course unaware of how to handle an SQLAlchemy instrumented attribute.

Comment: I'm using MySQL..

Comment: Then you should have a look at how [`DATE_SUB()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) / `-` operator works with INTERVALs. You may have to resort to using a [`text()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text) construct. It's prolly just in your example here, but your models are actually function definitions. Your query as it is would also end up performing a cross join, which usually is not what was meant.